# Value of sin-product only depended of argument difference

Tags: trigonometry

I have the product of 
$$Y_1 = A \sin (\omega t_1 + \phi_1)$$
and $$Y_1 = A \sin (\omega t_2 + \phi_2).$$

I know, since I plotted it with python, that the product $$X = Y_1 \cdot Y_2$$ is indepened of the $t_1$ and $t_2$, but depended on the difference $t_1-t_2$.
But I can not find any trigonometric identities which would proof this. Is there any trivial thing I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$ and $\cos(x-y) = \cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)$.

Subtracting these two equations, we find that:

$$\sin(x)\sin(y)=\frac{\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)}{2}$$

If we take $x= \omega t_1 + \phi_1$ and $y=\omega t_2 + \phi_2$, we get:

$$Y_1 \times Y_2 = A^2 \sin(x) \sin(y)= \frac{A^2}{2}\left(\cos(\omega (t_1-t_2)+\phi_1-\phi_2)+\cos(\omega(t_1+t_2)+\phi_1+\phi_2)\right)$$

So in general, the product depends not just on $t_1-t_2$ but also on $t_1+t_2$.

An easy way to see that the product must in fact depend on more than $t_1-t_2$ is to consider when $t_1$ is equal to $-\frac{\phi_1}{\omega}$. In this case, the product must be $0$ regardless of $t_2$. The difference can be anything. Same for $t_2 = -\frac{\phi_2}{\omega}$

One potential reason this might not have been reflected in your plot could be the range you use - if $t_1$ is very close to $t_2$, with say a difference of $\delta << 1$, $\cos(\omega(\delta))$ will be very close to $1$ while the other cosine term might not be.

Comment: Yes that was what I calculated somewhere too. But thinking back to university I am pretty sure, that $X$ only depends of the amplitude and the time difference. Might I miss a Special case? Like $\phi_1=\phi_2$ or something. Or is my memory just tricking me :-)